# Render an array in Block_view

Tags: theming

I want to render an array and print the output as Block[content]. There is either my Foreach or the way I use $item array or $row that is wrong. I will appreciate your help.

The result i get is the HTML I define in Block[content] without the values of $row->uri, $row->title, $row->body_value. They are empty. And it means I have done something wrong.

```
function produkt_block_view($delta = '')
{

  $block = array();

  $list = produkt_produkliste(1);    
  $items = array();
  foreach ($list as $row) {
    $items[1] = $row->uri;
    $items[2] = $row->title;
    $items[3] = $row->body_value;
  }


 switch($delta) {
  case 'produkt' :
    $block['content'] = '<a href="/19">';
    $block['content'] .= '<img class="pimg" src="'.$row->uri.'" alt="Se alle vores filter elementer her">';          
    $block['content'] .= '<p class="pname">"'.$row->title.'"</p>';
    $block['content'] .= '<p>"'.$row->body_value.'"</p>';      
    $block['content'] .= theme ('item_list',array('items' => $items, 'type' => 'ol',   'attribute' => 'produkt'));      
    break;   
  }

  return $block;
}
```

And I ended with this solution that get some results.

```
function produkt_block_view($delta = '')
{

   $query  = db_query("SELECT node.title,    field_data_field_kortbeskrivelse.field_kortbeskrivelse_value, file_managed.uri
    FROM node 
    JOIN field_data_field_tilh_rsforhold ON
    node.nid = field_data_field_tilh_rsforhold.entity_id

    JOIN field_data_field_kortbeskrivelse ON
    node.nid = field_data_field_kortbeskrivelse.entity_id

    JOIN field_data_field_billede ON
    node.nid = field_data_field_billede.entity_id

    JOIN file_managed
    ON field_data_field_billede.field_billede_fid = file_managed.fid  


    WHERE field_data_field_tilh_rsforhold.field_tilh_rsforhold_target_id = 30
    AND  field_data_field_billede.bundle = 'produkt_kategori'
    "

      );



    $rows   = array();
    foreach ($query as $row) 
    {
        $rows[] = array(
        $row->title,
        $row->field_kortbeskrivelse_value,
        $row->uri
      );
            print_r($row->uri);

            $block['content'] = '<a href="' . url(19) . '"><img class="pimg" src=/"'.   $row->uri . '" alt="Se alle vores filter elementer her" /></a>'; // assuming that anchor tag will wrap img          
            $block['content'] .= '<p class="pname">' . $row->title . '</p>';
            $block['content'] .= '<p>' . $row->field_kortbeskrivelse_value . '</p>';      
            $block['content'] .= theme ('item_list',array('type' => 'ol',     'attribute' => 'produkt'));      

    }


  return $block;
 }
```

Comment: What you expected to happen and what actually happened? You want to do something, you have a piece of code, but what's your *problem*? We will not create test environments only to test your code, if you will not even tell us what exactly you are trying to ask.

Comment: The result i get is the HTML I define in Block[content] without the values of $row->uri, $row->title, $row->body_value. They are empty. And it means I have done something wrong.

Comment: Please use [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/128196/edit) link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `$block['content'] = '<a href="/19">'; $block['content'] .= '<img class="pimg" src="'.$row->uri.'" alt="Se alle vores filter elementer her">';...` will work, `.` is a [string(concatination)](http://php.net//manual/en/language.operators.string.php) operator. You should create render array and assign it to `$block['content']`, example:

```
$array = array('#markup' => 'SOME HTML');
$block['content'] = render($array);
```

**EDIT:**

After below comments, I played a little with `hook_block_view` hook, and I found out some information about it:

- `$block[subject]` doesn't affect to its `content` even if you don't set it; `content` will be displayed without any `subject` (so, your missing `subject` doesn't cause any error here, as j.Reynolds mentioned);
- `$block['content']` can be string value and you don't need to render it, as Molot andj.Reynolds mentioned below, and you can concatinate it as many times as you want:)

So, if we return back to your snippet, you can try something like this:

```
$block['content'] = '<a href="' . url(19) . '"><img class="pimg" src="'. image_style_url('STYLE_NAME:E.G:LARGE', $row->uri) . '" alt="Se alle vores filter elementer her" /></a>'; // assuming that anchor tag will wrap img          
$block['content'] .= '<p class="pname">' . $row->title . '</p>';
$block['content'] .= '<p>' . $row->body_value . '</p>';      
$block['content'] .= theme ('item_list',array('items' => $items, 'type' => 'ol',   'attribute' => 'produkt'));
```

I don't know what `$row->uri` looks like in your code, but I assumed that it is something like `public://FILE_NAME.EXT`, if so you can use [image_style_url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7) function to generate image src..

Comment: Actually `$block['content']` may be a string, nothing extremely wrong with that. Renderable array should be preferred, but string is not a bug in itself, either.

Comment: @molot you are right. It can be a string. The code however has a lot wrong with it. I don't see a $block['subject'] which will be an issue. Of lesser issue is the non-closing anchor tag and the attribute key instead of attributes. And shouldn't attributes be an array?

Comment: @Mołot I see I've confused a little bit.. yes, you're right. But, block content won;t be displayed unless you render the content I think

Comment: The content must not be rendered. Theme does the rendering and returns html. You must populate $block['content'] with a string or a render array.

Comment: This is from the documentation - subject: The default localized title of the block. If the block does not have a default title, this should be set to NULL.
content: The content of the block's body. This may be a renderable array (preferable) or a string containing rendered HTML content. If the content is empty the block will not be shown. Which means OP's not setting the $block['subject'] is the show stopper. (or one of them)

Comment: @J.Reynolds oh, my bad. Looks like I'm tired a little bit after 10 hours of working day:)..

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for your comments and answers. But I still cant see how to get the value out of for instance $row->uri so my string can be complete. Where is it I do wrong?

Comment: @MahyarFarshi I edited my answer, added some aditional info..

Comment: @Xurshid29 - Hi again, I tried your code and I get this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in produkt_block_view() (line 112 of /var/www/ultraair.dk/public_html/sites/all/modules/produkt/produkt.module). And my Line 112 is: $items[1] = $row->uri;. It seems that my $items array is not getting populated.

Comment: @Xurshid, i could use your answer. It helped on the track. But I was forced to run my query in my produkt_block_view(). So I will accept your answer. But I wanna post my solution too in case somebody will see it.